# Run flyway in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, flyway

I use flyway container and it works well locally by:
`docker run -v ${PWD}/db/migration:/flyway/sql --rm flyway/flyway -mixed=true -url='jdbc:sqlserver://my-server.net;databaseName=TEST_DB' -user=$MSSQL_USER -password=$MSSQL_PW migrate`

I tried to use it in gitlab-ci, but the following does not work because the `docker run` part throws error - `cannot connect to docker daemon`.

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test-migration:
  stage: test
  services:
    - microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest-ubuntu
    - docker-hub/docker:dind
  variables:
    ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
    SA_PASSWORD: 'YourStrong!Passw0rd'
  script:
    - docker run -v ${PWD}/db/migration:/flyway/sql --rm flyway/flyway -mixed=true -url='jdbc:sqlserver://ssql-server-linux:1433;databaseName=TEST_DB' -user=SA -password='YourStrong!Passw0rd' migrate

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  services:
    - docker-hub/docker:dind
  script:
    - docker run -v ${PWD}/db/migration:/flyway/sql --rm flyway/flyway -mixed=true -url='jdbc:sqlserver://my-server.net;databaseName=TEST_DB' -user=$MSSQL_USER -password=$MSSQL_PW migrate
```

Instead of calling docker run, should use

`image: flyway/flyway` , and calling the command in the script section.

But I'm wondering about mounting the `volume` that is not supported in gitlab CI yet. 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3207

Any idea?

Comment: (Possibly) stupid question, out of curiosity: Is there an 'm' missing in front of `ssql-server-linux` in your JDBC string? I.e. instead of `jdbc:sqlserver://ssql-server-linux`, shouldn't it be `jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-server-linux` ? (without that, I don't get how the mssql-server-linux hostname used in the flyway command matches the SQL server container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cannot connect to docker daemon` means `DOCKER_HOST` is missing

After adding `DOCKER_HOST` in variables this works!

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-workflow-with-docker-executor

Mounting a volume also works, and the following works well.

```
script:
    - docker run -v ${PWD}/db/migration:/flyway/sql --rm flyway/flyway -mixed=true -url='jdbc:sqlserver://ssql-server-linux:1433;databaseName=TEST_DB' -user=SA -password='YourStrong!Passw0rd' migrate
```